# Confusion with the output of /\S\W/ and /\W\S/ in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.3

I just familiared with the `\W` and `\S`. Now i was playing to see how they behave and accordongly tried the below:

```
> s="abd12 de 5t6"
=> "abd12 de 5t6"  #understood
> /\W/ =~ s
=> 5               #understood
> /\W\S/ =~ s
=> 5               #Confusion(A)             
> /\S\W/ =~ s
=> 4               #Confusion(B) 
> /\S/ =~ s  
=> 0               #understood
>
```

What the logic ran in `Part-A` and `Part-B` to give the output as `5` and `4`. Just wanted to clear my concept there. In `Part-A` `5` indicates a `non-word character` but that is not `a non- white space charater` also.

I just want to know How `IRB` treat such statements in the `confusion - A and B`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `\W\S` in your regular expression, you are essentially saying: "Find a match in the string where a character is a non-word character, **followed by** a non-space character."

In `Confusion A` the first non-word character is the first space (at index 5). The next character right after it is the `d` which is a non-space character. That's a match and therefore returns 5 since that's the index where the match began.

Similarly, for the `\S\W` the first non-space character is `a`, but it's followed by `b` which is a word character, so the match doesn't work yet. Once it gets to the `2` (position 4), that matches a non-space character and it is followed by the space which is a non-word character.

Comment: Perfect explanation! You helped me to get on the right track! :) `+1` to you!